# Get object data from firebase using Ionic

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I'll try to explain this as clear as possible, since English is no my main language: I'm trying to get this object data, which is stored in a field called 'orders' inside a user document, basically every order I make through the shopping cart, it creates a new order inside the user document.

Sample data:

[image: db data]

I can access `pickuptime`, `location`, and `total` fields since they aren't inside the cart object using the following code:

```
constructor(private aF: AngularFirestore, private aS: AuthService) {
  const ordenes = aF.doc(`users/${this.aS.getInfo()}`);
  this.userOrders = ordenes.valueChanges();
}
```

`getInfo()` method just gets the current user uid.

Now when I try to display the data obtained from the document I just get to display the fields that are out of the cart object array.

This is my code to display data:

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-card *ngFor="let p of ((userOrders | async)?.ordenes)">
        <ion-card-header>
            <ion-card-title>{{ p.name }}</ion-card-title>
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content>
            <img src={{p.img}}>
            <br>
            <ion-card-subtitle>{{p.desc}}</ion-card-subtitle>
            <ion-row class="ion-align-items-center">
                <ion-col size="4">
                    <ion-label color="secondary">
                        <b>Total: {{ p.total}}</b>
                    </ion-label>
                </ion-col>
                <ion-col size="8" class="ion-text-right">
                    <b>Recoger en sucursal: {{p.sucursal}}</b>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
            <ion-row>
                <ion-col>
                    <b>Hora: {{p.horarecoger}}</b>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

Any Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but I think you are asking how do you access the `cart` element in your template.

In your database sample, though it isn't expanded, `cart` appears to be an array of maps.  Thus, elements like `p.img` don't refer to anything, as the `orders` array itself doesn't have an `img` member.

But this isn't trivial, since `cart` is an array.  So you'll need another `*ngFor` to enumerate the elements of that array.

I'm going to use a very simple html template to illustrate what you need to do, but this should allow you to do a similar thing in your full ionic template (as it will be easier for you to redesign the look of the template than for me to try to do that :).  Here you go:

```html
<div *ngFor="let p of ((userOrders | async)?.ordenes)">
  <ul>
    <li>Order Total: {{ p.total }}</li>
    <ul *ngIf="p.cart?.length > 0">
      <li *ngFor="let c of p.cart">Item: {{ c.amount }} - {{ c.desc }}</li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You also mention the `img` member and similar fields -- but you won't be able to access that either, since the outer loop already is only looping over the orders array, and `img` is on the outer object.  This is still reasonably easy to deal with, you just need to access it directly instead of using the loop.  Something like:

```html
<div *ngIf="(userOrders | async) as user">
  <img src="{{ user.img }}">
</div>
```